# Is using Lua in PHP feasible?

Tags: php, web-applications, lua

I would like to know whether it is feasible to use Lua code scripts in PHP, for a fairly critical and important web app.

What I would like to do is create scripts for different enviornments, so I don't have to write different PHP code for all of them.

Comment: To what end? How would the application benefit from parts in Lua? How would you interpret them, how would the code pieces interact?

Comment: That is what I wish to work on, but before that, I need to zero-in on a technology i can bundle with php. I found lua to be easy, and well, its a scripting language like PHP.

Comment: @Dragunov but *why*? Why do you need to bundle technologies in the first place? Why not use just one technology?

Comment: @Pekka ,the product am to be working on, is kind of a management software. Now, the environments it will work in, will be way different from one another. But still I need to keep it intact as a single product. So I thought, to tackle that issue, I create a simple and extensive backend, and use a scripting language to modify/construct it for the different environments, without using PHP again, as it might not be me writing the scripts again.

Comment: @Dragunov While I'm sure Lua is a much more beautiful language than PHP, there are relatively few people out there that can speak it. So from a business perspective, if you're worried about reusability, you're probably better off with PHP all the way. But I don't know Lua at all, maybe it has language features that make it a far superior scripting solution - I couldn't say. But from a technical perspective, mixing different languages like this usually adds obstacles

Comment: @Pekka Well, then I think, using a combination of PHP and XML would be far much more better than just using PHP. Thanks for the guidance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feasible ? Yes. There are packages for that. http://pecl.php.net/package/lua.

Good idea ? I strongly doubt it. What can you do in Lua that you can't in PHP ?

Comment: Possibly provide a safe and sand boxed environment for user scripts.

Comment: Yes, that is what am intending to do. Create a flexible backend in php and have the remaining scripting done in lua.

Answer (score 1):

The only show-stopper could be the state of development of the used lua extension. I've played around a little bit with the one you can find here:

http://repo.or.cz/w/phplua.git

It seems to be still active developed. I've never used it in production though, because i always wondered if PHP is still the right tool for the backend, if scripting is required. But if you already have the backend developed and just want to add scripting, it's probably a good way to go ...